# Java TLS that does not rely on DLP or prime factorization

Tags: java, windows, encryption, ssl

I'm writing a file server in Java on Windows using encryption that is resistant to Shor's algorithm.

My stumbling block is the SSL/TLS. From what I can gather, I can't use the standard java libraries as the socket encryption uses a Diffie-Hellman key exchange, which relies on the discrete logarithm problem.

I've looked into Salsa20, a new (ish) stream cipher, but the problem of securely exchanging keys remains. I've also looked at cyaSSL but the Java service provider doesn't support windows, and using C is not an option.

Can anyone provide any direction?

Comment: TLS in the title implies relying on standardized security procedures.  Creating methods resistant to QC is way beyond silly in my humble opinion.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Researching post-quantum key-exchange is important IMO. I just wouldn't use it yet.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe It's a uni final year project (we do a large project instead of a thesis) so it's more of a proof of concept than something that is actually going to have real world use.

Comment: Do you really need to use SSL/TLS?  Unless that is part of the specification, it sounds like overkill for your problem.  Instead, just do your cryptography against an ordinary TCP connection.

Comment: I'm not a cryptographer, so this might be a bad idea, but consider storing a symmetric key for each user (encrypted with the user's password) on the file server.  You can then pass the encrypted key to the client, which can decrypt it using the password the user enters.

Comment: @Harry Johnston - no, it's a terrible idea unless the system is only supposed to have a handful of users. For N users you need to manage N(N-1)/2 keys. Storing & indexing them quickly becomes a problem.

Comment: @Saf: I don't see why.  You need exactly one key per user, as far as I can see.  (Or do you mean "peer-to-peer network" when you say "file server"?)

Comment: You're right, sorry, that formula is only if the users need to communicate with each other. The reason I need SSL is to protect the users password, but even if someone has a users login & password they will still only be able to access encrypted AES files. 
For now I'm probably just going to have to use standard SSL. The functional spec for the project is here if anyone feels like looking at it. http://student.computing.dcu.ie/~rocher4/CA421project.html

Comment: see http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=226372

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two general approaches:

1. Use a pre-shared key

   No key exchange, no quantum problems. But now you need to distribute the shared key out-of-band, so it probably doesn't solve the problem.
2. Use a quantum proof key-exchange

   For example here is a spec for [NTRU](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-ntru-00) (only a draft, no real standard, and beware of patents)

   But in general asymmetric post-quantum crypto doesn't seem production ready.

Comment: Key size might be an issue. If Shor's in play, we should expect every other cracking method to be equally advanced. OTP would be our only saviour.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe There is no indication that a quantum computer can break symmetric crypto with sufficiently large keys (256 bit should be fine). It seems unlikely that a quantum computer will offer more than the halving of the effective key-size by using grover's algo.

Comment: I'm very uncertain about considering quantum computing. While familiar with the algorithms, my personal feeling is that any QC problem still lies in the [Pathological|NP] domain. If only moved to the hardware side.  Also the secure quantum link is only a link.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe keys longer than 256 bits are essentially physically impossible to brute force (e.g. requiring more than the entire energy output of a supernova to just run the counter through all 2^256 values). Various methods of cryptanalysis can usually be stopped by additional rounds and are rarely actually practical.  Symmetric crypto will be fine.

Comment: I've had a look at Ntru and the specifications. Bouncy Castle seems to have Ntru implemented, but looking at the source code, it doesn't have it for TLS. 
YaSSL DOES seem to have Ntru implemented for TLS, but not in the Java wrappers - it may be that I have to use inline C code for this.

In an ideal world I could find a Java implementation of the mode -
CipherSuite TLS_NTRU_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, but I can't find one anywhere.

Comment: I meant to paste CipherSuite TLS_NTRU_NSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  in the above post, given that RSA is equally broken in a quantum world.

Comment: @Saf There is a big difference. The system you use for confidentiality needs to be secure even against future attackers. The system you use for authentication only needs to be secure against current attackers. So NTRU_RSA is fine if you assume there will be large quantum computers 10 years from now, but there are none yet.

Comment: Security Innovations gave me a student license to use Ntru and sent me the files I needed, it's C code so it will require some hackery, but at least there is one solution.

Answer (score 1):

The outlook is bleak.

There are some Asymetrical crypto systems that are based on intractable problems that aren't DLP or factoring problems.  The [GGH Cryptosystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GGH_encryption_scheme) is based on the hard problem of closest vectors, for example.  You'll find there are a lot of signature schemes that are resistant to quantum cryptography, but not a lot of encryption systems, and the ones that do exist seem to all have some problem with their security.

As far as plugging GGH and Lamport Signatures into Java as an provider for SSL, that's another problem entirely.  You'll have to learn about how the JCE works and do a lot of legwork.

Comment: The OP might not need asymmetric crypto as such.  Typically file servers are not used anonymously, so there's probably a password or similar authentication method which can (perhaps) be leveraged to allow you to use symmetric crypto.  My suggestion to the OP was to store a symmetric key on the server for each user.  You'd need to store two copies, one unencrypted and one encrypted with the user's password.  During handshake, the server sends the encrypted version for the client to decrypt.  Are there known attacks against this sort of approach?